# Confusion regarding vector line integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vectors, line-integrals

Hi so I read online that the vector line integral
[image: the vector line integral] can be represented this way. But I also read that we can use [image: integration by substitution] when derivatives appear inside the integral.

So why is the last line still in terms of line integrals instead of definite integrals using integration by substitution?

Comment: Think of it as a scaling factor as you convert the parameterized 2d path to a 1d path.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has meanwhile hopefully read more [online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) and learned the simple basics about line integrals.

Answer (score 0):

The second to last line is in terms of definite integrals as you say. The working then proceeds to 'simplify' the result by writing it as a series of line integrals.

Comment: But shouldn’t the last line still be given in definite integrals?